# How to get maximum value from multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x

Problem description

my dataset looks like below

```
id   tre  f1   f2 f3 t1
1    2     0   1  1  er
2    3     1   0  0  po
3    abc   1   1  1  oo
4    yt    0   0  0  pp
```

I need to focus on f1,f2,f3..
create a new col based on f1,f2,f3....the values in the new col will be max(f1,f2,f3)
what function should I use

Answer (score 1):

```
df['max'] = df.apply(lambda x : max(x['f1'], x['f2'], x['f3']), axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `pd.DataFrame.max`

```
# test data
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO('''id,tre,f1,f2,f3,t1
1,2,0,1,1,er
2,3,1,0,0,po
3,abc,1,1,1,oo
4,yt,0,0,0,pp''')
df = pd.read_csv(data)


df['maxf'] = df[['f1', 'f2', 'f3']].max(axis=1)

output:
   id  tre  f1  f2  f3  t1  maxf
0   1    2   0   1   1  er     1
1   2    3   1   0   0  po     1
2   3  abc   1   1   1  oo     1
3   4   yt   0   0   0  pp     0
```

---

Edited: to find max of all columns start with `'f'`:

```
cols = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('f'), df.columns))
df['maxf'] = df[cols].max(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for this..I have f1.to..f23 columns...Im trying to use str.contains function to get all the columns starting with f can be grouped together instead of specifying one by one...is there any easier way to do this

Comment: Use can use `list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('f'), df.columns))` to select the list of columns start with `'f'`

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas [pandas.DataFrame.max](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html)

This should give you a new column with max values from all the 3 columns

```
df["max"] = df[["f1", "f2","f3"]].max(axis=1)
```

you can then run a max on this column to get max value

```
df['max'].max()
```